# c++ sorting values in vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I have one problem. I have vector of pointers which looks like:

```
vector < Pice*> popisPica;
```

(Object Pice has int method kolikoLjudiZeli() which returns integer.)

I have some objects in that vector, which i need to sort. But when i try to do that my program does nothing.

I have method

```
sort()
{
   for (int i=0; i<popisPica.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<popisPica.size()-1; j++)
            {
                if (popisPica[j]->kolikoLjudiZeli() < popisPica[j+1]->kolikoLjudiZeli())
                {
                    Pice *temp;
                    temp = popisPica[j];
                    popisPica[j] = popisPica[j+1];
                    popisPica[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Can u help me find mistake please? I'm clueless.

Thanx

Comment: Do you have to write your own sorting or can you use the standard library?

Comment: i need to write my own

Comment: You are not using i anywhere

Comment: we need a minimal compilable example which **reproduces the problem**.

Comment: @emartel: Doesn't matter, just doubles the work.

Comment: didn't you mean popisPica[ j + 1] = temp;  ?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath --- when i input values 2,3,1 in popisPica->kolikoLjudiZeli the output is the same (2,3,1) .. i see that compiler goes through the loop but i think that swapping is wrong bcz of pointers

Comment: @Kristijan: Better explicitly call out it's homework at the start, even if it's obvious enough imho. Avoid most downvotes and annnoyed readers.

Comment: Well if you must write your own sort then you should at-least learn about sorting algorithms like merge sort, quick sort or heap sort and use one of them as they are more efficient. Change your inner loop to start counting j from i instead of 0. And change the last line in your loop to popisPica[j+1] = temp;. That should fix it.

Comment: @KristijanDelivuk: let me emphasize the other part as well... **minimal compilable example**. you know, **code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
popisPica[j+1] = temp;   // instead of popisPica[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look what you've done here:

```
            Pice *temp;
            temp = popisPica[j];
            popisPica[j] = popisPica[j+1]; // not important
            popisPica[j] = temp; // assign popisPica[j] to popisPica[j] after all
```